How to change Celery worker concurrency in Django app
Recently I noticed that celery eats up a lot of memory in the server. One instance eating like 10% of mem
in processed I see quite default situation:
/usr/local/bin/python -m celery -A apps worker -l INFO -c 4 --logfile celery_worker.log
With threads it goes up to 14 instances
My idea was to cut concurrency to 2 (from process I suggest it is set to 4)
I've tried to do it in django settings
CELERY_WORKER_CONCURRENCY = 2

and event put in celery file
app.conf.update(
    task_soft_time_limit=60 * 60 * 1,  # 2 hours,
    task_time_limit=60 * 60 * 2,  # 3 hours,
    worker_concurrency=2  # 2 workers
)

But it did not work. I've checked it with
celery -A apps inspect stats

            "max-concurrency": 4,                                                                                           
            "max-tasks-per-child": "N/A",                                                                                               

but for example timeout was precessed correctly
can you suggest how to solve it?
